# Drawing linear function using JavaScript and HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, plot

What can be wrong in my code? I try to draw a linear function (y=a*x+b) typing **a** and **b** as a input and every time the line goes through the point (0,0) even though I set **b** != 0.
To do it I'm using canvas and JavaScript. And CSS as well, but the style of elements is not important here.

Can anyone point my mistake out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ploter</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #303030;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    h1,
    h2 {
      color: #ADADAD;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var canvas;
    var context;

    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("plotCanvas");
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    }

    function plot() {
      var a = document.getElementById("inputA").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("inputB").value;

      document.getElementById("funEquation").innerHTML = "y=" + a + "x+" + b;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      var x0 = 0.5 * canvas.width;
      var y0 = 0.5 * canvas.height;
      var scale = 40; //40px per 1 unit
      var x;
      var y;
      var dx = 4;
      var xMax = Math.round((canvas.width - x0) / dx);
      var xMin = Math.round(-x0 / dx);
      var axes = {};
      axes.x0 = x0;
      axes.y0 = y0;
      axes.scale = scale;

      drawAxes(context, axes);

      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = "white";
      context.lineWidth = 2;

      for (var i = xMin; i < xMax; i++) {
        x = dx * i;
        y = (a * x + b) / scale;
        if (i == xMin) context.moveTo(x0 + x, y0 - y);
        else context.lineTo(x0 + x, y0 - y);

      }
      context.stroke();
    }

    function drawAxes(context, axes) {
      var x0 = axes.x0;
      var y0 = axes.y0;
      var width = context.canvas.width;
      var height = context.canvas.height;
      var xmin = 0;
      context.beginPath();
      context.strokeStyle = "red";
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      //----Y axis----
      context.moveTo(xmin, y0);
      context.lineTo(width, y0);
      //----X axis-----
      context.moveTo(x0, 0);
      context.lineTo(x0, height);

      //---X arrow---
      context.moveTo(width, height / 2);
      context.lineTo(width - 15, (height / 2) + 10);
      context.moveTo(width, height / 2);
      context.lineTo(width - 15, (height / 2) - 10);
      //---Y arrow---
      context.moveTo(width / 2, 0);
      context.lineTo((width / 2) - 10, 15);
      context.moveTo(width / 2, 0);
      context.lineTo((width / 2) + 10, 15);

      //X - signs
      for (var i = x0; i < width; i += 50) {
        context.moveTo(i, (height / 2) - 7);
        context.lineTo(i, (height / 2) + 7);
      }
      for (var i = x0; i > 0; i -= 50) {
        context.moveTo(i, (height / 2) - 7);
        context.lineTo(i, (height / 2) + 7);
      }

      //Y - signs
      for (var i = y0; i < height; i += 50) {
        context.moveTo((width / 2) - 7, i);
        context.lineTo((width / 2) + 7, i);
      }
      for (var i = y0; i > 0; i -= 50) {
        context.moveTo((width / 2) - 7, i);
        context.lineTo((width / 2) + 7, i);
      }

      context.stroke();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Ploter XY</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div id="inputContainer">
        <label for="inputA">a:</label>
        <input id="inputA" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="inputB">b:</label>
        <input id="inputB" type="text" />
        <br />
        <p>Equation: <span id="funEquation"></span></p>
        <input id="confirmButton" type="button" value="Draw" onclick="plot()"></input>
      </div>
      <div id="plotContainer">
        <canvas id="plotCanvas" height="500" width="700" />
      </div>
      <section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: beside the scale, you need to take the values as numbers, not as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're taking `a` and `b` from input boxes, both of them are coming as string, you'll need to convert them to `Number` for the equations below to work.

Error occurs at following line

```
y=(a*x+b)/scale;
```

here if `x = 11, b = 22, x = 1` then since `a` and `b` are strings instead of mathematical addition there's a string concatenation performed. and value y becomes `1122/scale`

You'll have to change following

```
var a = Number(document.getElementById("inputA").value);
var b = Number(document.getElementById("inputB").value);
```

or a shortcut

```
var a = +document.getElementById("inputA").value;
var b = +document.getElementById("inputB").value;
```

There's one more error in the following code

```
x=dx*i;
y=(a*x+b)/scale;
```

You have to apply scale to both `x` and `y` not just `y`. It should be something like below

```
x=dx*i;
y=(a*x+b);

x /= scale;
y /= scale;
```

Also scale is too large which reduces the graph size for small values

Please find the working example below

```js
var canvas;
var context;

window.onload = function()
{
 canvas = document.getElementById("plotCanvas");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");

}

function plot()
{
 var a = Number(document.getElementById("inputA").value);
 var b = Number(document.getElementById("inputB").value);


 document.getElementById("funEquation").innerHTML = "y=" + a +"x+" + b;

 context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


 var x0 = 0.5 * canvas.width;
 var y0 = 0.5 * canvas.height;
 var scale = 1;  //40px per 1 unit
 var x;
 var y;
 var dx = 4;
 var xMax = Math.round((canvas.width-x0)/dx);
 var xMin = Math.round(-x0/dx);
 var axes={};
 axes.x0 = x0;
 axes.y0 = y0;
 axes.scale = scale;

 drawAxes(context,axes);

 context.beginPath();
 context.strokeStyle = "white";
 context.lineWidth = 2;

 for (var i=xMin; i<xMax; i++)
 {
  x=dx*i;
  y=(a*x+b);
  
  x /= scale;
  y /= scale;
  if(i==xMin) {
   context.moveTo(x0+x,y0-y);
  } else {
   context.lineTo(x0+x,y0-y);
  }
 }

 context.stroke();
}

function drawAxes(context, axes)
{
 var x0=axes.x0;
 var y0=axes.y0;
 var width=context.canvas.width;
 var height = context.canvas.height;
 var xmin = 0;
 context.beginPath();
 context.strokeStyle = "red";
 context.lineWidth = 5;
 //----Y axis----
 context.moveTo(xmin,y0);
 context.lineTo(width,y0);
 //----X axis-----
 context.moveTo(x0,0);
 context.lineTo(x0,height);

 //---X arrow---
 context.moveTo(width,height/2);
 context.lineTo(width-15,(height/2)+10);
 context.moveTo(width,height/2);
 context.lineTo(width-15,(height/2)-10);
 //---Y arrow---
 context.moveTo(width/2,0);
 context.lineTo((width/2)-10,15);
 context.moveTo(width/2,0);
 context.lineTo((width/2)+10,15);


 //X - signs
 for(var i=x0; i<width; i+=50)
 {
  context.moveTo(i,(height/2)-7);
  context.lineTo(i,(height/2)+7);
 }
 for(var i=x0; i>0; i-=50)
 {
  context.moveTo(i,(height/2)-7);
  context.lineTo(i,(height/2)+7);
 }

 //Y - signs
 for(var i=y0; i<height; i+=50)
 {
  context.moveTo((width/2)-7,i);
  context.lineTo((width/2)+7,i);
 }
 for(var i=y0; i>0; i-=50)
 {
  context.moveTo((width/2)-7,i);
  context.lineTo((width/2)+7,i);
 }

 context.stroke();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pl">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ploter</title>

    <style>
        body
        {
            background-color: #303030;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1, h2
        {
            color: #ADADAD;
        }   
    </style>

    <script src="app.js"></script>



 </head>
 <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ploter XY</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div id="inputContainer">
                <label for="inputA">a:</label>
                <input id="inputA" type="text" />
                <br />
                <label for="inputB">b:</label>
                <input id="inputB" type="text" />
                <br />
                <p>Equation: <span id="funEquation"></span></p>
                <input id="confirmButton" type="button" value="Draw" onclick="plot()" >
            </div>
            <div id="plotContainer">
                <canvas id="plotCanvas" height="500" width="700" />
            </div>
        <section>
    </main>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot. That's what I'm looking for.